# update next elements at the same level in the DOM

Tags: jquery

I have this code :

```
<div class="trackOn" id="line1">
    <span class="trackCounter">1</span>
    <span class="trackTime1">
        <select name="hours[]" class="trackInputDate" onChange="updateHours(this.value)" >
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>                
        </select>
    </span>
    <span class="trackTime2"></span>
    <span class="trackTime3"></span>
</div>

<div class="trackOn" id="line2">
    <span class="trackCounter">2</span>
    <span class="trackTime1">
        <select name="hours[]" class="trackInputDate" onChange="updateHours(this.value)" >
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>                
        </select>
    </span>
    <span class="trackTime2"></span>
    <span class="trackTime3"></span>
</div>

<div class="trackOn" id="line3">
    <span class="trackCounter">3</span>
    <span class="trackTime1">
        <select name="hours[]" class="trackInputDate" onChange="updateHours(this.value)" >
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>                
        </select>
    </span>
    <span class="trackTime2"></span>
    <span class="trackTime3"></span>
</div>

<div class="trackOn" id="line4">
    <span class="trackCounter">4</span>
    <span class="trackTime1">
        <select name="hours[]" class="trackInputDate" onChange="updateHours(this.value)" >
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>                
        </select>
    </span>
    <span class="trackTime2"></span>
    <span class="trackTime3"></span>
</div>
```

now, for example, if I select the value `3` from `#line2` I'd like to change the value of the next select boxex (so the ones on `#line3` and `#line4`) in `3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to attach the event handler with jQuery:

```
$('.trackInputDate').change(function() {
    updateHours($(this).val()); // or was `updateHours` supposed to be the 
                                // function that should handler the update?
    $(this).closest('.trackOn')
        .nextAll('.trackOn')
        .find('.trackInputDate').val($(this).val());
});
```

Reference: [`.closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/), [`.nextAll`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/), [`.find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

---

The DOM must be completely parsed before you can attach the event handlers. So either put the code in the [`ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) event handler:

```
$(function() {
   // code here
});
```

or put it at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Yeah updateHours() was the fucntion, but I can avoid it and use this event handler...much better :) anyway, I get this error `Object #<an HTMLSelectElement> has no method 'val'`

Comment: I currently have problems to connect to jsfiddle.net but I will provide a demo as soon as I can.

Comment: @markzzz: Ah that is a typo, I forgot `$` in front of `(this)`. Fixed.

Comment: :) Yes, but it can't get the select value. `$(this).val()` don't print the value...

Comment: @markzzz: It works for me. Make sure the code is in the `document.ready` handler or at the bottom of the page. Or I don't understand your problem.

Comment: Yeah now works! Just last think : if I put an `alert()` inside the event handler, this is called as time as the select that must be changed. In fact, if I edit them, the change is invoked every time I think. Is not so good this...

Comment: No ok! What I mean is that this function is not invoked 1 time, but every time the value is change by edit value with `val($(this).val());` : do you understand what I mean?

Comment: @markzzz: Ah I understood now... but anyway if it works now it's great :) No worries :D Happy coding! :)